# How to assign a default value to form input - Laravel 8

Tags: html, database, laravel, forms, ccsprite

I have a registration form that will get data from users and send it to database

here is one of the inputs in the view page:

```
<div style="font-family: Frutiger;" class="mt-4 text-right">
                    <x-jet-label for="name" value="{{ __(' * First Name') }}" />
                    <x-jet-input id="name" class="block mt-1 w-full text-right border" type="text" name="name" :value="old('name')" required autofocus autocomplete="name" />
                </div>
```

so i want to make this input optional and be able to submit the form without any value but if its left empty i want the default value to be for example "name"

is there any solution for this through this code or through Mysql?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? How is the given question related to  [tag:database]  or [tag:ccsprite]?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to set the initial value of the input to contain the value:

```html
<x-jet-input id="name" class="block mt-1 w-full text-right border" type="text" name="name" :value="{{ old('name') ?? 'Default value' }}" required autofocus autocomplete="name" />
```

Comment: Is the default value being set in the input?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have something like this in your controller that form data sent:

```
$request->validate([
    'name' => 'required',
    ...
]);
```

You should erase `'name' => 'required'` from this.

But if you get database error you should add this to your migration:

```
$table->string('name')->nullable();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Laravel 8 documentation, the `old()` helper function accepts a second argument as a default value :

```php
$value = old('field_name', 'default_value');
```

For more details see [Helpers - Laravel - The PHP Framework For Web Artisans](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-old)